# Minimal Logging in Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

While analyzing the performance of an `Azure SQL Database` with huge workload (Business-Critical service tier), I noticed the `Log IO Percentage` is hammered and hits 100% for considerable time periods, which as a consequence affects the overall performance. The database is being populated by several `Data factory` pipelines, that embody `SSIS` packages and stored procedures, and using `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statements extensively.

Back in on-premise world, I would change the database recovery model to `Simple` or `Bulk-Logged`, and use `TABLOCK` hint in my inserts, and the minimal logging is achieved (satisfying some other conditions).

Is this kind of minimal logging `(TABLOCK)` also applicable to `Azure SQL Databases` ? (I read they are in `Full` recovery model by default).

How to achieve minimal logging in the `Azure SQL Database` described above, using the same pipelines?

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/36400585-allow-recovery-model-to-be-changed-to-simple-in-az

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Subbu comments, this is not supported by now. You can vote up here to progress this feature. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/36400585-allow-recovery-model-to-be-changed-to-simple-in-az