# How to minimize logging during bulk data modification operations in Azure SQL?

Tags: azure-sql-database

In on-prem SQL Server one would switch the recovery model to 'simple' or 'bulk logging' to minimize logging during bulk data modification operations. Is there a similar feature in Azure SQL.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66441689/minimal-logging-in-azure-sql-database) is similar to mine. The link they provided is broken. I wanted to know if they added anything related during the past two years.
All the logging during these rare massive updates and inserts is causing big performance issues. I don't care about transactions logging. If anything goes wrong, I will do a restore.

I also wanted to know if the 'Accelerated database recovery' feature helps or if it's only useful for quick restores.

```
ALTER DATABASE [database_name] SET ACCELERATED_DATABASE_RECOVERY = ON;
```

Answer (score 0):

The default recovery model of an Azure SQL database is **FULL** and it can't be modified to any other recovery model as in on-premises recovery models.

The recovery model is set when the master database is created, meaning when an Azure SQL server is provisioned, the recovery model can't be modified because the master database is read-only.

To view the recovery model of an Azure SQL database, execute the following query:

```
SELECT name, recovery_model_desc FROM sys.databases;
```

You should get the following output:

[image: Figure 1.29: Recovery model of an SQL database Figure 1.29: Recovery model of an SQL database]

I have no experience with Accelerated database recovery but I suggest you to try it out and share the outcome here.